# Django form error handling architecture

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-validation

In the clean method of my form class I am working with many different inputs from the billing, contact, and account sections of the form. As such there are many self.add_error statements and many fields that depend on other fields in order to validate.

I have noticed that after adding an error for a field I am unable to access that field any more. This is strange as you can add more than one error to a field, but that is not the issue.

I am seeing this method grow more complicated and unreadable, is there a good way to do this so the person that comes after me will understand it? I don't feel that the code ordering to prevent access after error is appropriate. My only thought is to set error variables in clean and call a different method at the end to add the errors to the fields.

Thanks

Edit: To add, I am only returning after clean has run in order to give the user all errors at once. I did not feel that returning after each found error was a good user experience

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to provide your code to help people see what you are doing. This includes your error reports/traceback info.  Use the markdown options to help make your post more readable.

I could be wrong but from my own experience, I usually clean each field individually as per the documentation unless they rely on each other such as passwords, etc.

you can read this part of the documentation to help get some clarity:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute